# Let user choose their role while registering

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a registration feature, its working fine and user is able to register themselves, but I want now to improve it and let user choose their role, it can be worker/client.

This is all related stuff to that, I will just post main things:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
    try {
        logger.info("Received registration request for username: {}", signUpRequest.getUsername());

        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getEmail(), encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_CLIENT).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);
                        break;
                    case "mod":
                        Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(modRole);
                        break;
                    case "worker":
                        Role workerRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_WORKER).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(workerRole);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Role clientRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_CLIENT).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(clientRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);

        if (strRoles != null && strRoles.contains("worker")) {
            WorkerProfile workerProfile = WorkerProfile.createFromSignupRequestWorker(signUpRequest, user);
            user.setWorkerProfile(workerProfile);
        } else {
            ClientProfile clientProfile = ClientProfile.createFromSignupRequestClient(signUpRequest, user);
            user.setClientProfile(clientProfile);
        }

        userRepository.save(user);

        logger.info("User registered successfully: {}", user.getUsername());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error during user registration", e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new MessageResponse("Internal Server Error"));
    }
}
```

And react component:

```
const Register = () => {
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);

  const { message } = useSelector((state) => state.message);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(clearMessage());
  }, [dispatch]);

const initialValues = {
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    role: "CLIENT", // Default role selection
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
      .test(
        "len",
        "The username must be between 3 and 20 characters.",
        (val) =>
          val &&
          val.toString().length >= 3 &&
          val.toString().length <= 20
      )
      .required("This field is required!"),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("This is not a valid email.")
      .required("This field is required!"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .test(
        "len",
        "The password must be between 6 and 40 characters.",
        (val) =>
          val &&
          val.toString().length >= 6 &&
          val.toString().length <= 40
      )
      .required("This field is required!"),
  });

const handleRegister = (formValues) => {
    const { username, email, password, role } = formValues;
    setSuccessful(false);

    dispatch(register({ username, email, password, role }))
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        setSuccessful(true);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setSuccessful(false);
      });
  };
```

For some reason role is not being sent to backend, what I'm missing? How I should pass role that user select on front to back and actually save user in database with that role?

EDIT:

Some more code that should be important.

`auth.js`

```
    export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async ({ username, email, password, role }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await AuthService.register(username, email, password, role);
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(response.data.message));
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(message));
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue();
    }
  }
);
```

`auth.service.js`

```
    const register = (username, email, password, role) => {
  return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
    username,
    email,
    password,
    role,
  });
};
```

`User entity:`

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "users",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
    })
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set < Role > roles = new HashSet < > ();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ClientProfile clientProfile;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private WorkerProfile workerProfile;

}
```

`SignupRequest`

```
public class SignupRequest {

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 3, max = 20)
private String username;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 50)
@Email
private String email;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 6, max = 40)
private String password;

private Set < String > role;
}
```

Comment: Feels like a security risk in the making but alas. Your `auth.js` doesn't do anything with the role.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation? Check my updated code on that `auth.js`, I made some modification but its still same

Comment: Your auth.service still doesn't do anything with the role.

Comment: You're not helping on that way then

Comment: I edited it again, but its still same, I'm not seeing data role in payload under network